# Simplifying repeating variable names with increasing number

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to reduce these repeating variables for each of the 3 increasing variables that exist in the original code, this is because I need to repeat them all 50 times each to match how many rows of divs that exist in the original code:

```js
var dataA1 = $('.divA:nth-child(16)').text();
var dataA2 = $('.divA:nth-child(17)').text();
var dataA3 = $('.divA:nth-child(18)').text();
var dataA4 = $('.divA:nth-child(19)').text();
var dataA5 = $('.divA:nth-child(20)').text();

var dataB1 = $('.divB:nth-child(16)').text();
var dataB2 = $('.divB:nth-child(17)').text();
var dataB3 = $('.divB:nth-child(18)').text();
var dataB4 = $('.divB:nth-child(19)').text();
var dataB5 = $('.divB:nth-child(20)').text();

var dataC1 = $('.divC:nth-child(16)').text();
var dataC2 = $('.divC:nth-child(17)').text();
var dataC3 = $('.divC:nth-child(18)').text();
var dataC4 = $('.divC:nth-child(19)').text();
var dataC5 = $('.divC:nth-child(20)').text();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So is there a way of looping through the variable names `dataA` , `dataB` & `dataC` adding increasing numbers `++` to them?.

I suppose the same for the `:nth-child(16)` , `:nth-child(17)` , `:nth-child(18)` etcand I'm using jQuery so would like to keep using it to get this working if that's possible.

Thanks

Comment: Show your HTML - probably a way to do this in 1-2 lines and not 50

Comment: I'd also consider putting the data in a single object rather than all those variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a concept called [dynamic variable names](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript/), uses `eval()`.
Your code would look something like this:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  eval("var dataA"+i+" = $('.divA:nth-child("+(i+15)+")').text();");
}

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  eval("var dataB"+i+" = $('.divB:nth-child("+(i+15)+")').text();");
}

for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
  eval("var dataC"+i+" = $('.divC:nth-child("+(i+15)+")').text();");
}
```

More simplified:

```
const letter = ["A", "B", "C"];

letter.forEach(element => {
  for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    eval("var data"+element+i+" = $('.div"+element+":nth-child("+(i+15)+")').text();");
  }
});
```

`eval()` evaluates code represented as a string.

Comment: that eval() link to understand it was a big help and with your code and a little adapting it worked great thanks

Answer (score 2):

Loops!

Depending on how abstract you want to build this, you can do it with one or two loops to build a single Object variable with key/values. There are a few different ways to build these loops, all with similar results (i.e. do  you care if the keys are *1*-indexed or can they be *min*-indexed?).

*Note: without an HTML example it's not completely clear how the selectors should work. But this should be a good start.*

```js
var min = 4;
var max = 9;
var letters = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var data = {};

// for each letter
for (var l = 0; l < letters.length; l++) {
  var letter = letters[l]; // temp variable
  
  // for each integer between min and max (inclusive)
  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    var keyIndex = i - min + 1; // temp variable
    
    // set this value in the data object
    data['data' + letter + keyIndex] = $('.div' + letter + ' :nth-child(' + i + ')').text();
  }
}

// output the full data object
console.log(data);

// output each key/value
for (var key in data) {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(data[key]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="divA">
  <div>a-1</div>
  <div>a-2</div>
  <div>a-3</div>
  <div>a-4</div>
  <div>a-5</div>
  <div>a-6</div>
  <div>a-7</div>
  <div>a-8</div>
  <div>a-9</div>
  <div>a-10</div>
</div>

<div class="divB">
  <div>b-1</div>
  <div>b-2</div>
  <div>b-3</div>
  <div>b-4</div>
  <div>b-5</div>
  <div>b-6</div>
  <div>b-7</div>
  <div>b-8</div>
  <div>b-9</div>
  <div>b-10</div>
</div>

<div class="divC">
  <div>c-1</div>
  <div>c-2</div>
  <div>c-3</div>
  <div>c-4</div>
  <div>c-5</div>
  <div>c-6</div>
  <div>c-7</div>
  <div>c-8</div>
  <div>c-9</div>
  <div>c-10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful and I did try it and it worked but user2495207's answer just worked a bit nicer when adapting but that might have been my fault for not adding all the html. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

You don't need 150 individual variables, that's too much unnecessary bookkeeping. In the following example is a function that will accept any jQuery collection and extract the text out of each element then return a single string containing a comma delimited list of the entire text:

```
$('.A, .B, .C').extractText();
```

The heart of the function is jQuery method [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) which is very simular to the JavaScript method `.map()` except instead of returning a transformed array, the jQuery version returns a transformed jQuery object.

jQuery objects are very verbose when exposed directly so we'll use [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to *get* a simple array of DOM elements. The actual callback function uses the JavaScript property `.textContent` to extract the text:

```
let text = this.map(function() {
  return this.textContent;
}).get().join(', ');
```

`.get()` returns each of the elements' text as an array and `.join()` will return a the combined text of the array as a single string. If you want an array of strings (IMO a better way to handle multiple strings), pass a `false` flag (see example).

```js
$.fn.extractText = function(str = true) {
  let list = this.map(function() {
    return this.textContent;
  }).get();
  if (!str) return list;
  return list.join(', ');
}

const $abc = $('.A, .B, .C');

console.log(`Total Number of "div.A", "div.B", and "div.C" is ${$abc.length}`);

let ABC = $abc.extractText();

console.log(`A string of the entire text of all "div.A", "div.B", and "div.C"`)
console.log(ABC);

ABC = $abc.extractText(false);

console.log(`If an array of stings is need instead, pass the parameter as false (it's true by default)`)
console.log(ABC);
```

```css
.as-console-row::after { width: 0; font-size: 0; }
.as-console-row-code { width: 100%; word-break: break-word; }
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% !important; width: 80%; margin-left: 20%; }
```

```html
<div class=A>A01</div><div class=A>A02</div><div class=A>A03</div><div class=A>A04</div><div class=A>A05</div><div class=A>A06</div><div class=A>A07</div><div class=A>A08</div><div class=A>A09</div><div class=A>A10</div><div class=A>A11</div><div class=A>A12</div><div class=A>A13</div><div class=A>A14</div><div class=A>A15</div><div class=A>A16</div><div class=A>A17</div><div class=A>A18</div><div class=A>A19</div><div class=A>A20</div><div class=A>A21</div><div class=A>A22</div><div class=A>A23</div><div class=A>A24</div><div class=A>A25</div><div class=A>A26</div><div class=A>A27</div><div class=A>A28</div><div class=A>A29</div><div class=A>A30</div><div class=A>A31</div><div class=A>A32</div><div class=A>A33</div><div class=A>A34</div><div class=A>A35</div><div class=A>A36</div><div class=A>A37</div><div class=A>A38</div><div class=A>A39</div><div class=A>A40</div><div class=A>A41</div><div class=A>A42</div><div class=A>A43</div><div class=A>A44</div><div class=A>A45</div><div class=A>A46</div><div class=A>A47</div><div class=A>A48</div><div class=A>A49</div><div class=A>A50</div><div class=B>B01</div><div class=B>B02</div><div class=B>B03</div><div class=B>B04</div><div class=B>B05</div><div class=B>B06</div><div class=B>B07</div><div class=B>B08</div><div class=B>B09</div><div class=B>B10</div><div class=B>B11</div><div class=B>B12</div><div class=B>B13</div><div class=B>B14</div><div class=B>B15</div><div class=B>B16</div><div class=B>B17</div><div class=B>B18</div><div class=B>B19</div><div class=B>B20</div><div class=B>B21</div><div class=B>B22</div><div class=B>B23</div><div class=B>B24</div><div class=B>B25</div><div class=B>B26</div><div class=B>B27</div><div class=B>B28</div><div class=B>B29</div><div class=B>B30</div><div class=B>B31</div><div class=B>B32</div><div class=B>B33</div><div class=B>B34</div><div class=B>B35</div><div class=B>B36</div><div class=B>B37</div><div class=B>B38</div><div class=B>B39</div><div class=B>B40</div><div class=B>B41</div><div class=B>B42</div><div class=B>B43</div><div class=B>B44</div><div class=B>B45</div><div class=B>B46</div><div class=B>B47</div><div class=B>B48</div><div class=B>B49</div><div class=B>B50</div><div class=C>C01</div><div class=C>C02</div><div class=C>C03</div><div class=C>C04</div><div class=C>C05</div><div class=C>C06</div><div class=C>C07</div><div class=C>C08</div><div class=C>C09</div><div class=C>C10</div><div class=C>C11</div><div class=C>C12</div><div class=C>C13</div><div class=C>C14</div><div class=C>C15</div><div class=C>C16</div><div class=C>C17</div><div class=C>C18</div><div class=C>C19</div><div class=C>C20</div><div class=C>C21</div><div class=C>C22</div><div class=C>C23</div><div class=C>C24</div><div class=C>C25</div><div class=C>C26</div><div class=C>C27</div><div class=C>C28</div><div class=C>C29</div><div class=C>C30</div><div class=C>C31</div><div class=C>C32</div><div class=C>C33</div><div class=C>C34</div><div class=C>C35</div><div class=C>C36</div><div class=C>C37</div><div class=C>C38</div><div class=C>C39</div><div class=C>C40</div><div class=C>C41</div><div class=C>C42</div><div class=C>C43</div><div class=C>C44</div><div class=C>C45</div><div class=C>C46</div><div class=C>C47</div><div class=C>C48</div><div class=C>C49</div><div class=C>C50</div><script src=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js></script>
```

Comment: that is the way! this solution looks only ones the DOM when needed

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful with all the info provided and I did try it and it worked. However user2495207's answer just worked a bit nicer when adapting but that might have been my fault for not adding all the html. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, but keep in mind [`eval()` is a dangerous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!), and is very tempting to novices to use because it oversimplifies the use of strings.